# apache2 + django + mod_wsgi doesn't respond

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to deploy my working django app using apache2 + mod_wsgi module. This is my apache configuration:

```
anton@ru:~$ cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
Alias /static/ /home/anton/mysite/static/

<Directory /home/anton/mysite/static>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/anton/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

<Directory /home/anton/mysite>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and WCGI configuration:

```
anton@ru:~$ cat /home/anton/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/anton/mysite')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Using debug output (print 'bla-bla') I found out that wsgi.py works. But then http request doesn't get any response from apache. Could you please help me to understand why? Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
I've turned logs on like this:

```
ErrorLog /home/anton/error.log
CustomLog /home/anton/custom.log combined
```

Here is what happens in error log when reloading the service:

```
[Wed Nov 06 05:43:14 2013] [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Wed Nov 06 05:43:14 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Wed Nov 06 05:43:14 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.2+.
[Wed Nov 06 05:43:14 2013] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.3.
[Wed Nov 06 05:43:14 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

When requesting "mysite.com/" nothing happens in error.log and custom.log. Static data works:

```
85.141.191.57 - - [06/Nov/2013:05:44:37 -0500] "GET /static/main.css HTTP/1.1" 304 213 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36"
85.141.191.57 - - [06/Nov/2013:05:44:38 -0500] "GET /static/main.css HTTP/1.1" 304 212 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36"
```

**SOLUTION:**
The problem here was that python version didn't match the version of python mod_wsgi was compiled for. I built mod_wsgi from sources and that solved my problem.

Comment: Turn on Apache access and error logs.  Then look into the logs for information which may give clues as to your error.

Comment: Thanks, Austin! I've updated the post. Could you please have a look at it?

Comment: Can't see anything obviously wrong.  Check that there is a /home/anton/mysite/mysite/__init__.py file, as this will be required for Django's settings to be importable.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, but it is already there.

Comment: The Python patch level difference would not normally matter. The only time it would is if your Python installation was not installed with a shared library.

Comment: The link to documentation on specific issue of patch level difference is http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues#Python_Patch_Level_Mismatch

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

For why read:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Python_Simplified_GIL_State_API

In general it is also recommended that mod_wsgi daemon mode be used.

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html

although that shouldn't be the issue here.